# how to block the special character and smaller case characters in android EditText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm developing an android application. I'm using **android 2.3.3** for development.

Here in one screen I'm showing **text box (EditText)** and get the input from user.

The requirement is the restrict the **user to type only capital letters (only alphabets,numbers) and no special character allowed**

For that if I use **"InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS"** then it will allow only capital characters (only displays keyboard as capital letters) but it also allows special characters &, * etc.

But i need ,**that no special characters and the keyboard shows only the upper case letters**

Whether the above is possible in android or not?

All your ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
android:capitalize="sentences"
```

use the above line in the.xml file so that it only enters the alphabets and numbers only

Comment: I want to allow space ?

Comment: @LMK for space just use like "ABC DEF" means just add space anywhere inside this " "

Comment: I dont like the answer.. because if some one wants to change the language what should he do he doesnot even write any character ??